# authenticating gmail atom feed to return message count in 'PYTHON 3'

Tags: python-3.x, email, gmail, atom-feed

Hi guys so i wanna check my gmail mail account through python 3 and for that i am using the google's gmail atom feed,here is my code

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
url='https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom'
req=urllib.request.Request(url)
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData=resp.read()
numb=re.findall(r'<fullcount>(.*?)</fullcount>',str(respData))
print(numb)
```

now i want to return the `<fullcount></fullcount>`tag and once i run the code it throws an error `HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`
now i know this means i need to ad my gmail name and password but how can i do it?
note that i added "python 3' in caps because topics related to gmail atom feed authentication are old and only in python 2 using mostly feedparser or urllib2 which wont work in python3.
Thanks.

so people who mark this question as a duplicate are wrong you see the guy who marked this as a duplicate to a similar python 2 topic didnt exactly tell me how to translate the code in python 3 and there is still may attributes in the urllib in py2 like the HTTPBasicAuthHandler that is not in python 3 so please elaborate and answer properly 
this is a humble request from a noob
thanks again

Comment: You'd have to get yourself a [OAuth 2.0 token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: what is an Oauth token (k,ill google it) but i have seen people direcly add username and password in the url itself and it magically works?!

Comment: Ah, username and password also works; duped you to a Python 2 answer that is readily translated to Python 3 (replace `urllib2` with `urllib.request`)

Comment: umm sorry i did replace it with urllib.request but where do i exacly add the username and password?

Comment: and what about the urllib build opener thingy?

Comment: dude i need some serious help here,hope you reply soon